# Is there a way to check what object a decorated classmethod binds to?

Tags: python, reflection, python-decorators

I want to do some runtime type checking on a property that's decorated with `@classmethod` (making sure the classmethod decorates a property and not some other thing), but I don't see a way to do this through the "normal" ways (inspection with `vars()` or `dir()` or `.__dict__`):

```py
>>> class A:
...   @classmethod
...   @property
...   def d(cls):
...     return 'foo'
...
>>> A.d
<bound method ? of <class '__main__.A'>>
>>> A.__dict__["d"]
<classmethod object at 0x0000022ED4766130>
>>> A.__dict__["d"].__dict__
{}
```

Is there any way the check that the `classmethod` `A.d` binds a `property`?

I understand this might be peeking too far under the hood, and would be open to suggestions for how to accomplish this with type annotations as well!

This is not a straightforward application of `abc`, as this is a property whose presence depends on the presence of other properties, which I check at runtime for adherence to the data model.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Python 3.10 has `A.__dict__['d'] = <classmethod(<property object at 0x7fdb467cd670>)>`, but 3.6 has `A.__dict__['d'] = <classmethod object at 0x7f859550a8d0>`.

Comment: I'm using a relatively recent 3.11.3, (though the code in the post was from a 3.8 prompt) and I know they deprecated this particular sequence of decorators, but I'm more interested in *introspecting the classmethod object itself*

Comment: I built 3.11.3 and `A.__dict__['d'] = <classmethod(<property object at 0x7fdb467cd670>)>`, so this _is_ an option. You can look at the `classmethod` itself to find `A.__dict__['d'].__func__ = <property object at 0x7fa6cf6eac50>`.

Comment: `__func__` is what I was missing! Feel free to post an answer if you like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the `__func__` attribute of the `classmethod` instance to see that it is bound to a `property`.

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def d(cls):
        return 'foo'

A.__dict__['d']
A.__dict__['d'].__func__
isinstance(A.__dict__['d'].__func__, property)
```

```
<classmethod(<property object at 0x7fdb467cd670>)>
<property object at 0x7fa6cf6eac50>
True
```